# Unable to get button level with text box

Tags: html, css

I have a text box sitting next to a submit button, but for some reason I just can't get them to line up. I've tried adding a minus value margin but the browser appears to be ignoring this.

The HTML I'm using is:

```
<input type="text" id="toDoInput" /> 
<input type="submit" id="addToDo" value="" />
```

And the CSS is:

```
#toDoInput {
    background: #E6E6E6;
    border: 0px;
    border-bottom:3px solid #B1B1B1;
    color:000;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size:1.5em;
    margin: 10px;
    padding-left:5px;
    height:42px;
}

#addToDo {
    background:url(images/todo-input.jpg) #08a2f1 no-repeat center;
    height:47px;
    width:47px;
    colour:#61c5f9;
    border:0px;
    margin-left:-14px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-bottom:3px solid #0b90d4;
}
```

There's also a jsFiddle of the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/v5DuN/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most times I want to align inline-block elements, I need `vertical-align: middle`:

```
input {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v5DuN/9/)

<sup>Other `vertical-align` values can also work, though.</sup>